# Isolate y in trigonometric equation $x = \sqrt {\csc^2(y)-1} + y \csc^2(y) $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need to isolate *y* in the middle of cosecants. Is there a way to continue isolating the equation?

$x= \sqrt {\csc^2(y)-1} +  y \csc^2(y) $

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  That $y$ right next to the second $\csc^2(y)$ could cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it.
That $y$ by itself makes it impossible.

Just as solving
$y e^y = x$
for $y$
required the creation
of a new function
(Lambert W,
the fearless function),
so this would require
the creation of
a new function.

Comment: I never heard it called "fearless" before! Also, an obvious simplification is $\csc^2-1 = \cot^2$.

Comment: See "Lambert the fearless lion".

Comment: The only thing that I'm finding is "Lambert the Sheepish Lion".

Comment: That's it - my mistake. So make it Lambert the sheepish function